# Global Variable doesn't update onclick function

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons bound with a function that will update a global variable. Why do I have to click the button twice so then it'll update said global variable? 
https://jsfiddle.net/q9akn3gz/1/

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunc()"> 1 </button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="myFunc()"> 2 </button>
```

```
var val = 0;
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click',function() {
    val = 200;
});
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click',function() {
    val = 400;
});
function myFunc() {
    console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9akn3gz/2/). Just moved js code to JS section

Comment: not sure what the issue is ?,your fiddle updates the variable with one click as it should

Comment: Don't mix `onclick` with `addEventListener` -- you can't be sure which order they'll be called.

Comment: After going through some debugging, I noticed that `myFunc` is being invoked before `eventListener`. One can not be certain about the order of functions being called. Better call them serially!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `onclick` attribute was encountered before the `addEventListener` call, so it runs first, so you log first, then update.

It's considered bad practice to use onclick handlers with global functions, please stick to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Exactly. Which runs first is actually browser-dependent, but apparently in the OP's case, the `onclick` attribute handler runs before the `addEventListener` one does.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `onclick` attribute event handler, and call the same method in dynamically assigned event handler

check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9akn3gz/4/)

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn1">
1
</button>
<button id="btn2">
2
</button>

<script>
var val = 0;
 document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click',function() {
  val = 200;
  myFunc();
 });
 document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click',function() {
  val = 400;
  myFunc();
 });
function myFunc() {

 console.log(val);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function first and updating later. Your function prints to the console *Before* updating the value. Try moving the value update to the same function with `console.log(val)` and using the value operation before that line.

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="myFunc(200)"> 1 </button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="myFunc(400)"> 2 </button>

var val = 0
function myFunc(value) {
   val = value;
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: I came up with this concept but I have to hide the variable so it wasn't able to edit using `inspect element`. thanks btw.

Comment: @vistajess Your variable is global... if I want to, I can just pop open the console and type `val = 99999999`...

Comment: I will just wrap my scope using `(function(){ })();`

Comment: @vistajess: As Madara commented, global variables are also visible on the source. Try just typing `val` on the console with any of the answers here.

Comment: Ok thanks for some advices guys. It really helped me a lot :)